# how to share available content in textview using share option

Tags: android

I have developed an application. In this application, content is coming from database. The content I am getting in my textview , I just want to share the whole content using email etc..
How can I just send i.e share my available content.
I am getting all sharing options, but I am not able to share the content coming on screen.
Please let me know if you want more info!
Kindly Help me!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. You just need to put in your intent.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"yourEmail@gmail.com"});  
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,yourTextView.getText());
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Comment: i have done this but still I m not able to send.. the option take me to the place where i want to share but then suddenly it comes back without pasting that content or sharing that content.

Comment: Also , i am able to share content on gmail only, but not with message and whatsapp etc..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should obtain the text that you want to share. Secondly, you can use an intent in order to show to the user the different ways to share the content. You can use this code to achieve it:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textFromTextView);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
        "Share with..."));
```

I think AndroidWarrior's answer will only allow you to use e-mail but It's correct.